# MySQL Binary Logging Preventing Write Transactions - Bitnami

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, replication, bitnami, binary-log

I'm trying to configure MySQL on a Bitnami-prepared VM for replication (Not to be confused with MySQL With Replication from Bitnami), and I am having issues with its binary logging.

When I add the line `log-bin = mysql-bin` or `log_bin = mysql-bin` in the my.cnf file under `[mysqld]`, everything saves and MySQL restarts just fine. But when I test my application, only read transactions are working. Editing or creating new content fails.

I haven't found another cnf file that I'm conflicting with, and the bin logs do appear. But there seems to be some strange effects happening that I haven't encountered when configuring other MySQL servers in the past.

Anyone have an idea about what's going on?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your deployment? (i.e. where did you get such VM, versioning... etc)

Comment: If you deployed that VM in Azure, you may experience issues similar to the ones below: 
https://community.bitnami.com/t/mysql-with-replication-not-replicating/48547/10

Comment: Hey David. It was deployed through Azure, but it was not MySQL with Replication like is referenced in the post. I should have communicated that better. It's a deployed Bitnami MySQL 5.6.29-1 app on an Ubuntu 14.04 box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further digging and discovered that the culprit was our 'transaction-isolation' configuration. We have ours set to 'READ-COMMITTED' to help address locking issues, and this configuration does not allow 'STATEMENT' binary logging ('binlog_format'), which is the default setting on our server. The effect was restricting our transactions to read-only.

The solution was to set the 'binlog_format' to 'ROW' (or MIXED). Obviously people who might ever reference this shouldn't set that unless they know their system can operate under that condition, but in our case it's a viable option.

It certainly has nothing to do with Bitnami. Just a configuration restriction.